# Vector intersection with sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 26 $

Tags: vectors

$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 26 $ 
is the equation of a sphere with centre (0,0,0) and radius $\sqrt{26}$.

Find the points where the line through (3,-1,-2) and (5,3,-4) meets the sphere.

I know that line L would have the vector equation:

$L = \begin{cases}3+2t \\ -1+4t\\ -2 + (-2) t. \end{cases}$

I don't know where to go from here...

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

We have $$(3+2t)^2+(-1+4t)^2+(-2-2t)^2=26$$
Solving this gives $$2t^2+t-1=0$$ so $$t=\frac{1}{2}, -1$$
Giving $(4,1,-3)$ and $(1,-5,0)$ as the desired answer.

Comment: Should it be $(4,1,-3)$?